# How to get mobile device GUID?

Tags: windows-mobile

I need to have a mobile device ID for usage as a command line parameter. What are ways in Windows to retrieve it that do not involve writing your own program for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158773.aspx) is your answer. There is a sample code which you can download and see how it works.

Comment: Well, duh. Guess why i asked "ways that do NOT involve writing your own program"?

Comment: Ok.Try [this] http://marcusperryman.members.winisp.net/BlogStuff/CallGetDeviceUniqueID.zip link to see if it works for you. Otherwise i'll compile the sample from microsoft for you, but it will be in one or two days, since i don't have access to windows pc right now.

Comment: It worked. Though, i was hoping there exists a standard tool/utilite that allows to get this. If i wanted to make a program, i'd have used StackOverflow.

Comment: So this is a just a compiled sample that uses the microsoft api, so you can use it freely and you can check the source code to be sure exactly what it does.

Comment: I knew that after i saw VS 2010 solution files. )

Comment: Smae, though, that ActiveSync does not expose GUID.